# How do I remove icons for other drives on the unity bar?

Tags: unity, icons

My HDD is split into multiple partitions. They each have an icon on the Unity bar. Is there a way to remove them from the bar?

Comment: no even if its unmounted the icons are still visbl.
and i dont know why those icons are having a question mark as if icon missing or something "not recogniced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is something we should support. Please could you file a bug on Unity, I'll get it considered and a design for the various workflows worked out.

Comment: Mark, https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/711033 has been filed.

Answer (score 0):

Permanently? Not that I'm aware of. What you can do is unmount them, then they won't show up in the sidebar.